# Why is my CDT build configuration lost after I branch?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-cdt, subclipse

**Why does Eclipse CDT not understand my build configurations?** (Or are they not stored in the `.cproject` file?)

I use several build configurations in my project using Eclipse cdt and it works fine. I  have committed everything (using Subclipse) and created a branch.

When I check out the branch the build configurations are lost. The only configurations available are the standard Debug and Release. The `.cproject` file is version controlled and it is identical to the one committed.

I use

- Eclipse: Version: 3.7.0
- Cdt Version: 5.1.0.201002161416

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite practical, but the launching configurations are stored outside of the projects.

There is a `.launch` file per configuration in the `.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches\` in the `.metadata\` folder of your workspace.

Comment: Thank you Seki, but I still don't understand how to get this information into my recently checked out branch. Currently, the only work around I've found is to import configurations from my original project by hand. In Eclipse: Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Manage Configurations->New..->Import from projects. Should this not be done automatically when I check out my branch?

Comment: @JayS: I am sorry, I made a confusion between launching configuration and project settings. In my cdt projects, the **C/C++ settings** are in the `.settings` folder of the project, in the `org.eclipse.cdt.core.prefs` file. You need to import that directory into svn trunk. For your existing branch then you will have to merge the folder adding revision to get it on the next update.